# Trigger a pipeline jenkins job by commits from multiple repositories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline (jenkins) job, which uses multiple repositories.

The repositories are checkout out like this:

`checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', ...])`

Now I want to trigger the job when a commit is done to *any* of the repositories. How can I configure this?

Comment: I started a bounty, but I have further question regarding this. How to make the changes in the other repos appear in change log. It seems to be only taking changes from one repository(the first one)

Comment: Webhooks are a great solution to trigger a build on commit. For gitLab the webhook is defined in gitlab and not in jenkins so you can have multiple hooks to the same build. I don't know how that works with other tools.

Comment: Yeah, Google ideal. Unfortantly My git solution does Not Support webhooks

Comment: I second that. It seems that jenkins is constantly building even though nothing changes.

Comment: Something like this should work ind dsl speak, have you tried it like this:
    multiscm {
           git {
               remote {
                   github('jenkinsci/jenkins')
            }
            extensions {
                relativeTargetDirectory('jenkins')
            }
        }
        git {
            remote {
                github('jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin')
            }
            extensions {
                relativeTargetDirectory('job-dsl-plugin')
               }
             }
         }

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by using a freestyle job that kicks off the pipeline.  Have the multiple SCM plugin and than the freestyle job has the web hooks.

Comment: @eddieWhat happens when you push dependent changes to two or more repos in a short time? Do you get multiple jobs triggered (many of which fail)? How do you pick up all the related changes? I'm thinking about a scenario where, say, you push a breaking change to a library (repo 1) and also the fixes for the change to the clients (repos 2, 3, ...)

Comment: Two scenarios would happen.  1. the first build would break (change from repo 1) and the 2nd/3rd would fix it.   or they would all not break but you'd have two versions that would have issues with them.  Since it is breaking changes you should know about this ahead of time. 

Note, this is a workaround.  In a better-designed application structure, you'd point to the library you want in the app config file.  Only when you account for the changes would you change to the new lib.

Comment: Thanks. I was just struggling with a similar scenario.

Comment: I would recommend using a project management tool like maven or ant.

Comment: I still don't understand how a single Jenkins job can be triggered from changes in multiple repos. Is it at all possible?